# Sinc series convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\textrm{sinc}(an)$ converge? And if it does to which value?
Does $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\textrm{sinc}^2(an)$ converge and to what value? $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I have read that if $a=1$, then both series do converge.

Comment: Dirichlet test?

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple,
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(an)}{an} &= \dfrac{ia}{2} \left(\ln(1-e^{ia}) - \ln(1 - e^{-ia})\right)\cr
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{\sin(an)}{an}\right)^2 &= \dfrac{\pi^2 - 3 \;\text{polylog}(2,e^{2ia}) - 3 \;\text{polylog}(2,e^{-2ia})}{12 a^2}\cr}
$$
which would make your sums
$$ 1 + i a \left(\ln(1-e^{ia}) - \ln(1 - e^{-ia})\right)$$
and
$$ 1 + \dfrac{\pi^2 - 3 \;\text{polylog}(2,e^{2ia}) - 3 \;\text{polylog}(2,e^{-2ia})}{6 a^2}$$